# Attach large files in javamail in base64

Tags: java, io, jakarta-mail

Currently I am attaching files (small) in mail as follows:

```
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file)); 

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
String contentType = "application/octet-stream";
String base64Content = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(byteArray));

messageBodyPart.setContent(base64Content, contentType);       
messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachment.getFileName(),
                                            CharEncoding.UTF_8, null));
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

But reading the file to a `byte[]` at a time won't work for large files. But at the end I want to put attachments in base64 encoded string in email. So how can I tackle large files in attachment here?

Comment: About how large are we talking?

Comment: like 100mb or so.. may be more..

Comment: You are aware that most Mail Servers will deny messages of that size? I suggest using some sort of cloud space where you can upload that stuff and include a link in the mail for the client to download (or not if they chose to).

Comment: yes.. normally the maximum size is around 25 mb, but I want my code to be OOM proof.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Reading files of 100 MB and more into memory certainly won't improve OOM behavior.

Comment: The main purpose of this program is to send zipped log files (large) inside organisation emails. So attachment size limits mostly does not matter here. All I want is to successfully transfer log files as attachments. May be I can create multiple 100mb files and send them over via multiple mails. But I need to successfully attach and send at least 1 100mb file.

Comment: OK, one more question: Why does it have to be email? IMHO one of the least appropriate techniques to do this. If you are inside a company network only, you could even use a local server for data distribution. Just send links to a company-internal share. Mail-Server Admins will roast you over a hellfire for sending that large files.

Comment: What can I say! THIS is the requirement :)

Comment: The company might be served better by asking the right questions at the right time instead of just implementing every requirement popping up. I'd say this might be the perfect time for the question "Why on earth would anyone want to do that via email?"

Comment: While I am totally with Sami, I see that you are probably not in the position to question the requirement. Frankly, I wouldn't want to be in your shoes now. I hesitate to suggest you escalate this to your manager since it is really complete nonsense but that may be quite difficult for you - easy to say for me. But even if you managed to do it, it will certainly backfire sooner or later.

Comment: I just +1ed the question to attract viewers. Maybe someone has a good idea for a solution. But really: I do not consider this to be a good requirement in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor for understanding my position.

Comment: [Base64.getMimeEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getMimeEncoder-int-byte:A-) with line length might be an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [MimeBodyPart.attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
messageBodyPart.attachFile(file, "application/octet-stream", "base64");
```

The file won't be read into memory, it will be encoded "on the fly" as the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try with it to send whatever file you want. Also any number of files.

```
/**
 Multi part message email
 **/

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

//Add atachments
String[] attachments = new String[2];

attachments[0] = "your_complete_path.pdf";
attachments[1] = "your_complete_path.txt";

if(attachments != null && attachments.length > 0) {
    for (String str : attachments) {
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(str);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
}

message.setContent(multipart);
```